# What are some alternatives to a NOT IN query?

Tags: sql, database, performance

Let's say we have a database that records all the Movies a User has not rated yet. Each rating is recorded in a MovieRating table.

When we are looking for movies user #1234 hasn't seen yet:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Movies 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT movie_id FROM MovieRating WHERE user_id = 1234);
```

Querying NOT IN can be very expensive as the size of MovieRating grows. Assume MovieRatings can have 100,000+ rows.

My question is what are some more efficient alternatives to the NOT IN query? I've heard of the LEFT OUTER JOIN and NOT EXIST queries, but are there anything else? Is there any way I can design this database differently?

Comment: What is your DBMS? (Also mention that you don't want `JOIN` query as well - but it's an option)

Comment: You are assuming a particular execution strategy. SQL Server for example does not care how you write this query.

Comment: Postgres, but I'm willing to use anything else, including nosql or graph dbs - as long as it can solve this problem :)

Comment: You've listed the 3 logical ways to go about this, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, and `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE`. There are no alternatives to one of those three that would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated sub-query using WHERE NOT EXISTS() is potential your most efficient if you have to do this, but you should test performance against your data.

You may also want to consider limiting your results both in terms of the select list (don't use *) and only getting TOP n rows. That is, you may not need 100k+ movies if the user hasn't seen them. You may want to page the results.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Movies m
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM MovieRating r 
                    WHERE user_id = 1234 
                      AND r.movie_id= m.movie_id)
```

Comment: This indeed was the fastest for what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mock query, because I don't have a db to test this, but something along the lines of the following *should* work.

```
select m.* from Movies m
left join MovieRating mr on mr.user_id = 1234
where mr.id is null
```

That should join the movies table to the movie rating table based on a  user id. The where clause is then going to find null entries, which would be movies a user hasn't rated.

Comment: Does a left join go through all the rows first? If so does complexity / execution time grow linearly with the size of MovieRating?

Comment: Complexity would not grow, but it doesn't matter what database engine you use, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc etc... As a database grows, queries will take longer (marginally longer unless you're dealing with extremely large databases, 100,000K rows isn't that large)

Comment: Not if you have an index on MovieRating.USER_ID = then it would just seek to those rows, join those to Movies, and return the NULL rows as the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT M.*
  FROM Movies as M
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       MovieRating as MR on M.id = MR.movie_id 
                        and MR.user_id = 1234
 WHERE M.id IS NULL
```

Comment: An `inner join` would never return results.

Comment: I know .. It is not an inner join :P